# Getting User ID from Windows Store?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have an application on the Windows Store and in that application I am trying to get some kind of ID that represents that users Windows Store account. How can I do this?

I found this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=netframework-4.8
and this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.getcurrent?view=netframework-4.8

That gets me the username of the current user in windows, which I believe should be reflect what they have logged into the Windows Store with, but am not sure if that will always be consistent. Is there something better?

Comment: What do you want to do with this ID?  If it's likely to reveal *anything* personal about the user then I would very much hope Microsoft do not make it available.

Comment: @trojanfoe e.g. build your own Licensing system?

Comment: @derHugo But what information can Microsoft supply to your app that doesn't reveal personal information that could be harvested etc?

Comment: Don't know but I would expect that any account in the MicrosoftStore/Microsoft account has a unique public ID anyway? This ID doesn't reveal any personal information but might be something like `23a7f7ea0123` ... As I understand the only thing OP asks for is a unique Identifier for the logged in user .. it doesn't need to contain any further information

Comment: Well the OP is investigating username currently and that is far more revealing that a randomly generated hex string.

Comment: It's just an unique identifier for banning. It can be anything that is consistent to a user's windows store account.